# CKeditor Laravel.Connecting file manager to upload images from computer

Tags: php, image, laravel, ckeditor, editor

I need to upload images from computer, when I use CKeditor. At basic version you can only use links of images in Internet. I tryed to use Laravel library UniSharp - https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager
I made all like in documentation, but when I try to upload images - I take error

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
>   (1/1) TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 68)

It looks like red line , when I upload images.

[after upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odS0V.png)

I searched a lot, but nothing helped. Maby somebody know how to do it? Or other solutions of my problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you get errors related with TokenMismatch, it's usually because you have not declard csrf field in your form. When you are using a POST method, you have to use csrf helper function like this.

```
<form action="/yourroute" method="POST">
{{ csrf_field() }} //declare your csrf field like this
//form elements here
</form>
```

If you are making an AJAX request, make an AJAX setup to include CSRF token for POST request like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
 });
```

Alos use meta tags for CSRF token like this in your layout file if you are using ajax setup and want to initialize CSRF automatically.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```